# Match warning and pattern-matching in SML

Tags: sml

I was wondering what would be a good strategy to understand if pattern-matching in `SML` will proceed the `Match` warning.

Consider the following function:

```
fun f 7 (x,y) = x * 5.1 | f x (y,#"a") = y;
```

From first glance, it looks like it does not provide the `Match` warning. But if I'll run it, it will.

From my point of view, we handle all of the cases. which case we don't handle? even if `f 7 (x,#"a")` we know which case should be (first one).

My question is, how to decide that the function will output that waning.

Also, I would be glad for an answer why the following function is invalid:

```
fun f (x::xs) (y::ys) (z::zs) = y::xs::ys::zs;
```

without `zs` its valid. how does `zs` change it?

Comment: How about `f 8 (x,#"b")`?

Comment: @hnefatl Oh right, didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how to decide that the function will output that waning.

The compiler has an algorithm that decides this.

Either use the compiler and have it warn you, or use a similar heuristic in your head.

See [*Warnings for pattern matching*](http://moscova.inria.fr/~maranget/papers/warn/) by Luc Maranget (2007).

It covers the problem, algorithm and implementation of finding missing and duplicate patterns.

---

A useful heuristic: Line patterns up, e.g. like:

```
fun fact 0 = 1
  | fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
```

and ask yourself: Is there any combination of values that is not addressed by exactly one case of the function? Each function case should address some specific, logical category of the input. Since your example isn't a practical example, this approach cannot be used, since there are no logical categories over the input.

And `fact` is a bit simple, since it's *very* easy to decide if it belongs to the categories `0` or `n`.

And yet, is the value `~1` correctly placed in one of these categories?

Here is [a practical example](https://github.com/exercism/haskell/commit/473b7b37b197989862e42abbe860923a20acc64c) of a function with problematic patterns:

```
fun hammingDistance [] [] = SOME 0
  | hammingDistance (x::xs) (y::ys) =
    if length xs <> length ys then NONE else
    if x = y
      then hammingDistance xs ys
      else Option.map (fn d => d + 1) (hammingDistance xs ys)
```

It may seem that there are two logical cases: Either the lists are empty, or they're not:

1. The input lists are empty, in which case the first body is activated.
2. The input lists are not empty, in which case they have different or equal length.

   1. If they have different lengths, `NONE`.
   2. If they have equal lengths, compute the distance.

There's a subtle bug, of course, because the first list can be empty while the second one isn't, and the second list can be empty while the first one isn't. And if this is the case, the second body is never hit, and the distinction between different / equal lengths is never made. Because the task of categorizing is split between pattern matching and *if-then-else* with precedence to pattern matching.

What I do personally to catch problems like these preemptively is to think like this:

- When I'm pattern matching on a list (just for example), I have to cover two constructors (1. `[]`, 2. `::`), and when I'm pattern matching on two lists, I have to cover the Cartesian product of its constructors (1. `[]`, `[]`, 2. `[]`, `::`, 3. `::`, `[]`, and 4. `::`, `::`).
- I can count only two patterns/bodies, and none of them aim to cover more than one of my four cases, so I know that I'm missing some.
- If there had been a case with variables, I have to ask how many of my common cases it covers, e.g.

  ```
  fun hammingDistance (x::xs) (y::ys) =
      if x = y
        then hammingDistance xs ys
        else Option.map (fn d => d + 1) (hammingDistance xs ys)
    | hammingDistance [] [] = SOME 0
    | hammingDistance _xs _ys = NONE
  ```

  Here there's only three patterns/bodies, but the last one is a catch-all; `_xs` and `_ys` match all possible lists, empty or non-empty, except if they're matched by one of the previous patterns first. So this third case accounts for both of 2. `[]`, `::` and 3. `::`, `[]`.

  So I can't simply count each pattern/body once. Some may account for more than one class of input if they contain very general patterns via pattern variables. And some may account for less of the total input space if they contain overly specific patterns via multiple constructors. E.g.

  ```
  fun pairs (x::y::rest) = (x, y) :: pairs rest
    | pairs [] = []
  ```

  Here `x::y::rest` is so specific that I'm not covering the case of exactly one element.